# How to take back our domain name?

Tags: web-hosting, domains

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question but I couldn't find the right stack-exch site to ask this.
 We have registered a domain name a year ago and unfortunately we missed renewing the registration and domain expired. Seems there was an bot that registers such expired domains so Now that we want to take the domain name back it is very hard.
 I even could not find the registerer's info on sites like whois. So please if you had similar experience let me know what did you do to take back your domain name.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 7):

If the registrar is in the U.S. you may be able to reclaim the domain if it contains your company trademark. The [Anticybersquatting Consumer Protection Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticybersquatting_Consumer_Protection_Act) passed in 1999 was created specifically so companies can prevent other people from owning a domain that dilutes their trademark. So any domain similar to or containing your trademark would apply. This also protects you from typosquatters as well.

However, if it's a generic domain and you never trademarked the domain name itself, then you're SOL.

Answer (score 2):

I know your pain, the same thing happened to me before.

Usually you would have to contact the person who "sniped" you and ask them, but the reason they do the sniping in the first place is to get money out of you to get your domain back.

What I ended up doing was just to switch TLD, from .com to .org - you can try this, or get a similar but different domain name (for instance add a hyphen if there are two words in the name)

Best of luck!

Comment: It would be best to not be a part of the market for those domain grabbers.  If only everyone who had a domain taken away would agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, they've not stolen it from you. It expired and they bought it. You could try and use a service that will grab it for you if it's available again but there you are.

Comment: Aside from either paying well over the odds for your domain name or waiting for it to become available again, the best thing that you can do for yourself if ensure that you buy from a domain registrar that gives you good notice of domain expiry. Then make sure that the e-mail address you have registered with them is monitored.

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I disagree with 'you can't.' There are several ways to get a domain name back, I don't understand why this has been upvoted twice.